# Trying to save the image to the database as well as show it in view in codeigniter using ajax only works after page loads

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Created a normal upload image system and uploaded the image to the database now when i click on upload the image does not show itself on the div assisgned but i have to reload the page again to see that uploaded image what can i use to show the image with ajax submit

here is the code

```
<div id="timelineProfilePic"><?php 
{
    $image_properties = array('src'=> base_url("uploads/" . $image_file),'width' => '200px','height'=> '200px','id'=>'profilepic','rel'   => 'lightbox');


    echo img($image_properties);
   ?>
   <div id="profilepicselector">
<?php echo form_open_multipart('',["id"=>"form_profile"]); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ;?>" >

<?php echo form_upload(["name"=>"imagefile"]); ?>

<?php echo form_submit(["name"=>"submit","value"=>"Submit"]); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?></div>

jQuery('#form_profile').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var url= '<?php echo base_url("user/do_upload"); ?>';
        formData.value

        jQuery.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data)
            {

                $('#profilepic').attr('src',data);
            },
            error: function(data){
            //error function
            }
       });            
    });

public function do_upload()
  { 
      $config = [
                'upload_path' =>    './uploads',
                'allowed_types' =>    'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',
                'max_size'            => 1100000000,
                'max_width'            => 102400000,
                'max_height'           => 76800000,
                 ]; 
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $this->upload->initialize($config); 
       if($this->upload->do_upload('imagefile')) 
       {

            $post = $this->input->post();
          unset($post['submit']);
          //print_r($post);

          $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
          print_r($upload_data);

          $file_name=$_FILES['imagefile'];
          $this->load->model('Pmodel');
          $this->Pmodel->upload_model($post,$file_name);




      $image_path_profile= base_url("uploads/".$upload_data['raw_name'].$upload_data['file_ext']);
        } 
        else
        {
         $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
         $this->load->view('dashboard/profile',compact('upload_error'));
        }
  }
```

Comment: share console.log(data)....
Also, in ajax call why you loading a view....

Comment: when i add console.log(data) it shows error

Comment: should i share the raw data ?

Comment: <h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
  <p>The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.</p>

Comment: when i use console.log(data) it shows error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the error it was a silly mistake. i needed to echo the image path so that it will change when i click on ajax submit at the end like this

echo $image_path_profile= base_url("uploads/".$upload_data['raw_name'].$upload_data['file_ext']);

this will return the image at the same time i am uploading it.

thanx for your reply